# CSS grid absolute positioning relative to a display:contents div

Tags: css, blazor

I am trying to build a Blazor component to offer a context menu fotr each row on a CSS grid.
The component would wrap the row cells with a display:contents Css to prevent disturbing the grid layout.
It would also have a position:relative so a contextmenu with a position:absolute could be display relative to the row.
But any child div with position:absolute inside the row gets positioned relative to the grid itself, not relative to the row.
Is it even possible to use position:relative on a display:contents div?
Following demo should ilustrate the issue:

```
<div class="Grid" style="display:grid;grid-template-columns:min-content min-content;grid-column-gap:10px;">
    <div>cell1</div>
    <div>cell2</div>
    <div>cell1</div>
    <div>cell2</div>
    <div>cell1</div>
    <div>cell2</div>

    <div style="position:relative; display:contents; color:red"
         @oncontextmenu="@(()=>isShowingMenu = !isShowingMenu)"
    @oncontextmenu:preventDefault>

        <div>right click for context menu</div>
        <div>right click for context menu</div>

        @if (isShowingMenu)
        {
            <div style="position:absolute; border:1px;background-color:aquamarine">
                Context menu
                </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div>cell1</div>
    <div>cell2</div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool isShowingMenu;
}
```

Comment: "Is it even possible to use position:relative on a display:contents div?" No it isn't. But you could use a subgrid instead of display:contents to avoid messing up your grid. The subgrid can be `position:relative`.

Comment: Thanks Alohci, but  then I can't use min-content for column widths. There should be a way to position a row context menu on a CSS grid.